# Mirror the entire ASF SVN repository?

Tags: svn, repository

I am trying to Mirror the whole ASF SVN repository from http://svn-master.apache.org/dump/.
I have already unzipped the 7z file **svn-asf-public-r1164364-1178131.7z** using 7za, but when I typed the command:

```
svnadmin load test < svn-asf-public-r1164364\:1178131
```

it came out:

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1164364
svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction '0-0', 
path 'commons/proper/chain/branches/version-2.0-work/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/chain/impl/CatalogBase.java'
* editing path : commons/proper/chain/branches/version-2.0-work/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/chain/impl/CatalogBase.java ...
```

I don't understand why. Do I need to download the 14Gb file i.e the original revision 1164364? What should I do after downloading the original revision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the complete revision history of ASF's Subversion repository, then you have to download all 7z archives from [the page](http://svn-master.apache.org/dump/) and `svnadmin load` them into a clean repository one by one.

- The file `svn-asf-public-r0:1164363.7z` contains revisions `0:1134363`,
- Later revisions `1164364:1621932` are divided into multiple archived dumps. Take a closer look at filenames.

[SVNBook | Repository Maintenance](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate):

> As Subversion dumps each new revision, **it outputs only enough
>   information to allow a future loader to re-create that revision based
>   on the previous one**. In other words, for any given revision in the
>   dump file, only the items that were changed in that revision will
>   appear in the dump. The only exception to this rule is the first
>   revision that is dumped with the current svnadmin dump command.